# what are image labels

Tags: magento-1.7, magmi

in the link: `https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor`

**It has given as:**

```
To set base image labels
image_label (label to use for image)
small_image_label (label to use for small_image)
thumbnail_label (label to use for thumbnail image)
```

**A) What are Image labels?**

**B) Where should I set it?**

**BTW, below are my feed column names:**

```
store,websites,type,attribute_set,is_affiliate_product,status,visibility,qty,is_in_stock,tax_class_id,weight,name,meta_keyword,description,sku,manufacturer,price,merchant_buy_link,remote_image_url,main_category,color,for,shoe_type,short_description,remote_thumbnail_image_url,category_ids,merchant_name,merchant_id,small_image
```

**Below is 1 row sample data"**

```
admin,base,simple,Affiliate Product,1,Enabled,"Catalog, Search",1,1,None,1,Ed Hardy Girls Bird Flower Cap - White,"handbags, wallets, designer handbags, prada, gucci, burberry",The  Ed Hardy&nbsp;Girls Bird Flower Cap  is an adorable cap for little girl.&nbsp;This cap features front tattoo  Bird Flower  graphics Embroidered print  adjustable Back  It also has printed text graphics with the words &#34; Ed Hardy &#34;. Your little,F58-EH5GH124UBRD,Ed Hardy,11.99,http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-6521002-10569016?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fashion58.com%2Fitemdetail.asp%3Fmod%3DEH5GH124UBRD,http://www.fashion58.com/itemimages/5GH124UBRD.jpg,Hats & Caps > Caps,White,,,The  Ed Hardy&nbsp;Girls Bird Flower Cap  is an adorable cap for little girl.&nbsp;This cap features front tattoo  Bird Flower  graphics Embroidered print  adjustable Back  It also has printed text graphics with the words &#34; Ed Hardy &#34;. Your little,http://www.fashion58.com/itemimages/5GH124UBRD.jpg,73,Fashion58,123,
```

**C) Anything wrong in column names or sample data?**

**D) Iam unable to display product remote images in my site.. iam sure iam doing something wrong with Magmi.**

pls kindly tell me..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party extension.

Answer (score 1):

A) Image labels are exactly that, a label name for the image. This would be used either internally or to use with the `title` attribute on `img` tags in your templates.

B) They are set in the backend in catalog/product management under the images tab.

C) Try it, see if there are errors.

D) I'm not sure what you mean. Are you trying to use images loaded from other websites? That seems ethically questionable, and aside from that, there are technical reasons why that is a bad idea. If the images are used on your site, they should be served from there as well or you risk those images not being available once those site owners decide to change file names (or, worse, send you a C&D).